# About how many fibers can I create in ZIO on one machine?

Tags: scala, zio

I realize the exact number depends on a whole lot of things, so I’m really looking for an order of magnitude on say, a MacBook Pro.

Is it 100s of 1000s? Millions?  More?

For example I’ve calculated I can run about 1M goroutines on this machine and I’m trying to get a sense of ZIO fibers would be about the same or more…

Comment: Not sure about **ZIO** but the **Cats-effect** docs answer this: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/concepts#fibers - And since they both are similar I would guess the concrete values of both will be relative close.

Answer (score 1):

The primary resource consumption from a fiber is going to be the heap memory it consumes, plus (arguably) the memory consumed by the closure capturing its state.  Because JVMs (and even different GC algorithms within a JVM) differ in how many bytes in memory a given object will take up, and this can even depend on runtime settings (e.g. if the heap is 32GiB or smaller, object references can be encoded in 32 bits, while a heap larger than that will require more space for each object reference).

On "typical" JVMs, the memory overhead of fibers is in the low hundreds of bytes.  This is also approximately the overhead of an Akka actor (which can, like a goroutine, a ZIO fiber, a Cats Effect fiber, or a Scala future, be considered a means of modeling a process in a more efficient way than a thread (this ignores the substantial philosophical differences in the particulars of the respective models)), and it's well-established that substantially greater-than a million actors can be created per GiB of heap, so it's reasonable to expect that multiple millions of fibers can be created per GiB of heap.

It should be noted that it's impossible for more fibers to be consuming CPU at any point in time than you have cores/threads, so it's absolutely possible, if you have far more fibers/goroutines/actors ready to consume CPU, you may see a substantial latency effect from fibers waiting to be scheduled (so-called "thread starvation").